# Getting this socket error in discord.js and can't debug it

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, discord.js

I always get the following error in every single one of my three discord.js bots and I have absolutely no idea what it could be and how to debug it:
[image]

Copy Paste:

```
events.js:179
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
    at Client.emit (events.js:177:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.onError (H:\njs\tosbot\node_modules\di
ient\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
    at WebSocket.onError (H:\njs\tosbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event
16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at _receiver.cleanup (H:\njs\tosbot\node_modules\ws\lib\webso

    at Receiver.cleanup (H:\njs\tosbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiv
    at WebSocket.finalize (H:\njs\tosbot\node_modules\ws\lib\webs
)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
```

Of course I can't post the full code here but if you are interested or need to look at it, I have both [this one](https://github.com/Sv443/sBot) and [this one](https://github.com/Jabrils-Discord-Server/ToS-Bot) on GitHub which both regularly crash due to this error.

Comment: Please add the relevant code that causes the error.

Comment: @CodeF0x as I said in the question I can't. I don't know where it's coming from and I also can't possibly post thousands of lines of code. That's why I added the GitHub links